# Return element name and value as key value pair

Tags: xquery, xquery-3.0

I am working on a requirement where I need to return element name and value as Key value pair as below using XQUERY.

[code=123,px_last=value attribute of first data,last_update=value attribute of 2nd data and so on]

There are 7 data element with attribute value inside should be read as above with first field mapped to first data and second mapped to second data value attribute.
etc..

With your help I was able to generate the output but got struck where I need to map the first field element to first data attribute value and so on etc.

Thanks in advance

XML file:

```
<root>
<fields>
    <field>PX_LAST</field>
    <field>LAST_UPDATE</field>
    <field>LAST_UPDATE_DT</field>
    <field>SECURITY_DES</field>
    <field>FUT_CUR_GEN_TICKER</field>
    <field>YLD_CNV_BID</field>
    <field>YLD_CNV_ASK</field>
</fields>
<Datas>
    <Data>
        <code>0</code>
        <ins>
            <id>CT30</id>
            <key>Govt</key>
        <ins/>
        <data value="98.843750"/>
        <data value="16:14:45">
        </data>
        <data value="06/03/2014"/>
        <data value="T 3 3/8 05/15/44"/>
        <data value=""/>
        <data value="3.439"/>
        <data value="3.437"/>
    </Data>
    <Data>
        <code>0</code>
        <ins>
            <id>US0001W</id>
            <key>Index</key>
        <ins/>
        <data value=".119000"/>
        <data value="06:46"/>
        <data value="06/03/2014"/>
        <data value="ICE LIBOR USD 1 Week"/>
        <data value=""/>
        <data value="N.A."/>
        <datavalue=".11900"></data>
    </Data>
</Datas>
</root>
```

XQuery:

```
declare function xf:strip-namespace($e as element())
as element()
{
element { xs:QName(local-name($e)) }
{
  for $child in $e/(@*,node())
   return
 if ($child instance of element())
 then
   xf:strip-namespace($child)
 else 
   $child
 }
};

let $nl := "&#10;"

let $count := 0

for $x in       doc("test.xml")/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/dlws:retrieveGetDataResponse/dlws:instrumentDatas//*
let $y:=xf:strip-namespace($x)
return
if($y/name() = 'instrumentData')
then
concat($nl,'[','')
else if($y/name()='data')
then
  concat($y/name(),'=',$y/data(@value),',')
else if($y/name() != 'instrument')
then
  concat($y/name(),'=',$y/text(),',')
else
()
```

Output right now:

[code=123,data=werr,data="qwe",data="wer",......,]
  [code=456,data=rty,data="tyuu",data="uuu",......,]

Answer (score 2):

Generally, if you can break your problem into smaller pieces, it will facilitate a simpler solution that more closely resembles the problem itself.

```
declare function local:make-pair(
  $e as element()
) as xs:string?
{
  typeswitch($e)
    case element(data) return concat(local-name($e), '=', $e/@value)
    default return concat(local-name($e), '=', $e)
};

let $idatas :=
<idatas>
 <idata>
    <code>123</code>
    <data value="wer"></data>
    <data value="sdf"></data>
    <data value="zxc"></data>
    <data value="asd"></data>
    <data value="jgh"></data>
    <data value="cvb"></data>
    <data value="bsz"></data>
 </idata>

 <idata>
    <code>345</code>
    <data value="ff"></data>
    <data value="zxd"></data>
    <data value="wvver"></data>
    <data value="wencvr"></data>
    <data value="wzxcer"></data>
    <data value="wmmer"></data>
    <data value="wuuer"></data>
 </idata>
</idatas>
for $idata in $idatas/idata
let $pairs := 
  for $p in $idata/*
  return local:make-pair($p)
return concat('[', string-join($pairs, ','), ']')
```

Answer (score 2):

In the following parts of the answer, I completely ignored the `strip-namespace` part, which is a bad idea anyway. Eighter declare it as default namespace and don't worry about it any more, or use `local-name()` instead of name, or use the wildcard namespace mather`*:elementname*`.

---

*The input was modified during updates of the question. Everything up to the next horizontal bar refers to the first revision of the question.*

You can do all the "string manipulation foo" with very few code using some XQuery 3.0 features, especially calling functions in axis steps and the string concatenation operator `||`:

```
//idata/(                      (: for all idata elements :)
  "[" ||
  string-join((                (: combine all key/value pairs with commata :)
    "code=" || code/data(),    (: code header :)
    data/("data=" || @value)), (: data fields :)
  ',') ||
  ']')
```

And it *exactly* fits into one line on Stack Overflow (if you really want it)!

```
//idata/("["||string-join(("code="||code/data(),data/("data="||@value)),',')||']')
```

With the output being

> [code=123,data=wer,data=sdf,data=zxc,data=asd,data=jgh,data=cvb,data=bsz] [code=345,data=ff,data=zxd,data=wvver,data=wencvr,data=wzxcer,data=wmmer,data=wuuer]

A probably more readable version with explicit loops, still using the concatenation operator (which in my opinion enhances readability):

```
for $idata in $xml//idata
return
  "[" || string-join((
    "code=" || $idata/code/data(),
    for $data in $idata/data
    return
      "data=" || $data/@value),
  ',') || ']'
```

---

For the **updated question**, a one-liner will probably get too unreadable. The modified code in the end just joins with the index of the data element:

```
for $dataset in /root/Datas/Data
return
  "[" || string-join((
    "code=" || $dataset/code/data(),
    for $data at $position in $dataset/data 
    let $field := /root/fields/field[$position]
    return
      $field || "=" || $data/@value),
  ',') || ']'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.I will follow your suggestion.

Comment: I was able to get the data as requested above and would like to thank you both,but it is getting complicated now as the requirement is to map fields as below

[code=123,px_last=abc,last_update=...]
[code=4656,px_last=ttr,last_update=...]

There are 7 data element with attribute value insde <idata> and should be read as first field name=first data attribute value and so on for the the 7 fileds

i.e. px_last=wer,last_update=sdf and so on for each data
etc..

your help is again much appreciated

Comment: Please post data actually representing your problem (by editing your question) together with the expected output for that input.